# Como mantenerme del bucle de mi menu

Tags: java, poo

yo otra vez. Les tengo una pregunta sobre como mantenerme en un ciclo que  contiene otras instrucciones. Coloco parte de mi codigo para que me entiendan.

```
while(mascotas_asignadas < 4)
{
    System.out.println("De acuerdo a la informacion ingresada, usted tiene " + mascotas_asignadas + " Mascotas asignadas, por lo que se le puede asignar una mas");
    if(familia1.getNiniosMenores() > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Dado que su familia tiene " + familia1.getNiniosMenores() + " Niños menores, puede escoger uno de los perros en la siguiente lista");      
        System.out.println("   "+perros_pequenios[0]);
        System.out.println("1. "+perros_pequenios[1]);
        System.out.println("2. "+perros_pequenios[2]);
        System.out.println("3. "+perros_pequenios[3]);
        System.out.println("4. "+perros_pequenios[4]);
        System.out.println("5. "+perros_pequenios[5]);
        System.out.println("6. "+perros_pequenios[6]);
        System.out.println("7. "+perros_pequenios[7]);
        System.out.println("Escoja una de las opciones de arriba, luego presione enter");
        int opcion = scaner.nextInt();

        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                perro1.setNombrePerro("Bruno");
                perro1.setEdadPerro(9);
                perro1.setSaludPerro(100);
                perro1.setRazaPerro("Beagle");
                perro1.setColorPerro("Cafe con manchas blancas");
                perros_pequenios[1] = "No disponible";
                mascotas_asignadas = mascotas_asignadas+1;
                System.out.println("Se le ha asignado a: " + perro1.getNombrePerro()+ "\nEdad: " + perro1.getEdadPerro() + "\nSalud: " + perro1.getSaludPerro() + "\nRaza: " + perro1.getRazaPerro() + "\nColor: " + perro1.getColorPerro());
                System.out.println("Desea adoptar temporalmente a otro perro?\nSi no lo desea, por favor presione 0 y luego enter");
            break;
```

mascotas asignadas es una variable que lee lo que introduce el usuario. Si coloca mas de 4 pues no puede asignarse otra mascota, pero digamos que en este caso si puede. Lo que yo quiero hacer es de que cada vez que se asigne una mascota ademas de sumarle 1 a la variable, quiero que le pregunte si desea asignarse otra mascota o no. Si desea asignarse otra mascota quiero que vuelva a correr los casos. Es decir como que si nunca le hubiera preguntado. Como lo podria hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a ver si puedo ponerte un poco de luz, aunque resulta difícil, pues has limitado demasiado el código de tu pregunta y resulta algo complicado adivinar el contexto.

Al no tener las clases, he adaptado el código para hacerlo funcional creando variables y un array bidimensional para mostrar y grabar los datos

```
//creo la clase mascotas para el ejemplo
public class Mascotas {
    //creo array bidimensional para reproducir un poco tu código y hacer funcional el ejemplo
    static String[][] perros_pequenios = new String[8][5];
    //instaciamos la clase scaner para todos los métodos
    static Scanner scaner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //creamos el método main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        //creamos variables de enteros para el ejemplo
        int mascotas_asignadas;
        int ninos_menores = 1;
        
        //damos valores al primer término del array (primer valor (columna) de cada fila)
        perros_pequenios[0][0] = "Bruno";
        perros_pequenios[1][0] = "Pablo";
        perros_pequenios[2][0] = "Cuqui";
        perros_pequenios[3][0] = "Chiqui";
        perros_pequenios[4][0] = "Rafi";
        perros_pequenios[5][0] = "Tobi";
        perros_pequenios[6][0] = "Pipa";
        perros_pequenios[7][0] = "Paqui";

        //creamos un bucle do while que repetirá mientras se introduzca un número menor diferente a 9 (elegido al azar, podría ser el 4 que tienes en tu código)
        //el 9 cierra el programa
        do {
            //pedimos ese número y lo almacenamos en la variable
            System.out.println("Mascotas asignadas: (9 para salir)");
            mascotas_asignadas = scaner.nextInt();
            
            //Si introducimos un 9 cierra el programa, si no:
            //el condicional lo agregué para el ejemplo, no sé de donde 
            //recibes tú los datos, así que yo me lo he inventado y lo he 
            //puesto en 1 para que siempre se cumpla la condición
            if (mascotas_asignadas == 9){
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if (ninos_menores > 0)
            {
                //si se cumple, llamamos al método y le enviamos el valor de 
                //las dos variables por parámetro
                metodoMascotas(mascotas_asignadas, ninos_menores);
            }
        //ésta condición hará que se repita el bucle mientras mascotas_asignadas sea diferente de 9
        } while (mascotas_asignadas != 9);
    }
    //creamos el método que recibe las variables por parámetro
    public static void metodoMascotas(int mascotas_asignadas, int ninos_menores){
        //creamos otra variable entera que igualamos a la recibida por parámetro
        int mascotas = mascotas_asignadas;
    
        //creamos otro bucle que indica que mientras la variable anterior sea mayor a cero se repetirá
        while (mascotas > 0) {
            //imprimimos la información por pantalla con el valor de las variables
            System.out.println("De acuerdo a la informacion ingresada, usted tiene " + mascotas_asignadas + " Mascotas asignadas, por lo que se le puede asignar una mas");
     
            //mostramos el menú con los primeros valores de cada fila del array
            System.out.println("Dado que su familia tiene " + ninos_menores + " Niños menores, puede escoger uno de los perros en la siguiente lista");
            System.out.println("1. " + perros_pequenios[0][0]);
            System.out.println("2. " + perros_pequenios[1][0]);
            System.out.println("3. " + perros_pequenios[2][0]);
            System.out.println("4. " + perros_pequenios[3][0]);
            System.out.println("5. " + perros_pequenios[4][0]);
            System.out.println("6. " + perros_pequenios[5][0]);
            System.out.println("7. " + perros_pequenios[6][0]);
            System.out.println("8. " + perros_pequenios[7][0]);
            //pedimos que se elija una opción
            System.out.println("Escoja una de las opciones de arriba, luego presione enter");
            //capturamos la opción
            int opcion = scaner.nextInt();

            //en función de esa opción, toma el case correspondiente
            switch (opcion)
            {
                case 1:
                    perros_pequenios[0][1] = "9";
                    perros_pequenios[0][2] = "100";
                    perros_pequenios[0][3] = "Beagle";
                    perros_pequenios[0][4] = "Cafe con manchas blancas";
                    mascotas_asignadas++;
                    System.out.println("Se le ha asignado a: " + perros_pequenios[0][0] + 
                        "\nEdad: " + perros_pequenios[0][1] + 
                        "\nSalud: " + perros_pequenios[0][2] + 
                        "\nRaza: " + perros_pequenios[0][3] + 
                        "\nColor: " + perros_pequenios[0][4]);
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
                case 2:
                    perros_pequenios[0][1] = "6";
                    perros_pequenios[0][2] = "100";
                    perros_pequenios[0][3] = "Border Collie";
                    perros_pequenios[0][4] = "Blanco y Negro";
                    mascotas_asignadas++;
                    System.out.println("Se le ha asignado a: " + perros_pequenios[0][0] + 
                        "\nEdad: " + perros_pequenios[0][1] + 
                        "\nSalud: " + perros_pequenios[0][2] + 
                        "\nRaza: " + perros_pequenios[0][3] + 
                        "\nColor: " + perros_pequenios[0][4]);
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            }
            //el bucle se repetirá mientras la variable sea mayor a 0, por lo que en cada iteración, descontamos 1 a la variable
            mascotas--;
        }
    }                  
}
```

En mi ejemplo te puse dos bucles, uno que te pedirá el número de mascotas indefinidamente mientras no introduzcas un 9. Y el segundo que hará tantas iteraciones como número de mascotas asignadas introduzcas

Comment: gracias amigo, tome la idea de lo que me dijiste y corrió mi programa tal y como necesitaba, muchas gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Agregando un do-while

```
do
{
//El código que se repite hasta que opción sea 0
}while(opcion!=0);

Tomando en cuenta que el bucle se convertirá en infinito y no se detendrá nunca.
```

Comment: El problema de fondo del OP es que no sabe como funciona el do-while. Esta respuesta tampoco lo explica. La respuesta debería al menos mostrar el código completo; si no, puede que el OP lo malinterprete.